# Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2

Tags: android, travis-ci

For some reason, travis [build](https://travis-ci.org/RajuSE/mortar-evolution-stone/builds/199128927) is having a hard time resolving dependencies.

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':mortar'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mortar:classpath'.
 Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
mortar-evolution-stone:mortar:unspecified
```

[Travis Ci](https://travis-ci.org/RajuSE/mortar-evolution-stone/builds/199128927)

Comment: `because no repositories are defined`... Your `build.gradle` file, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 because no repositories are defined

In `mortar/build.gradle` you have no repostiories.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
  }
}
```

But, you shouldn't need that there... your `/build.gradle` can set that up.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    // *** Add this *** //
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Really, you don't need `mortar` in your code-base at all.

`app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {   
    ...
    // compile project(':mortar') // ** Remove this ** //
    compile 'com.squareup.mortar:mortar:(latest version)'
}
```